# permission denied when executing the jenkins sh pipeline step

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have some trouble with this situation:
everytime I create a new pipeline job ( entitled "pipeline"), the `sh` step won't work even with simple command like `ls` or `pwd` and it returns this log:

```
sh: 1: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/pipeline@tmp/durable-34c21b81/script.sh: Permission denied
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you use

```
stage(name){
   sh ./runSomething
}
```

Jenkins always uses to user jenkins for running scripts. There are some possibilities:

1. Jenkins is running with a different user, maybe you start it with some other user.
2. Something went running when installing jenkins, check that you have a jenkins user

Comment: did not work for me

Answer (score 18):

I was getting a similar permissions denied error after following the Jenkins pipeline tutorial for a node project.

> ./jenkins/test.sh: Permission denied

The original pipeline Test stage looked like the following and returned that error.

```
stage('Test') {
    steps {
        sh './jenkins/test.sh'
    }
}
```

I found the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61956744/9109504 and modified the Test stage to the following

```
stage('Test') {
    steps {
        sh "chmod +x -R ${env.WORKSPACE}"
        sh './jenkins/test.sh'
    }
}
```

That change fixed the permissions denied error.

Comment: This will change all of the files in the workspace to be executable, not exactly what you want. `sh "chmod +x ./jenkins/test.sh"` would target just the one file.

Answer (score 1):

From the terminal you should give permission to this file

```
sudo chmod -R 777 ./test.sh
```

and when you push this file it will go with this permissions under the hood,  and this way Jenkins will execute this file.

Comment: did not work for me

Answer (score -5):

We just need to add "sudo" before the path. I have tested It. It workes perfectly.

```
stages {
    stage('Hello') {
        steps {
        
            sh 'sudo /root/test.sh'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did not work for me

Comment: calling script in jenkins using "sudo" sounds dangerous...