# Permission denied error - jenkins (shell script)

Tags: git, bash, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using a jenkinsfile to test one of our instances.
For this I created a bash script.
Problem is that jenkins doesn't have permissions to run the script. Any idea how to fix this?

Jenkinsfile:

```
 stage("Testing instances"){
    if (terragruntAction == 'apply' || terragruntAction == 'test'){
       echo "Testing"
       sh '../check_services.sh'
    }
 }
```

output:

> ../check_services.sh: Permission denied

I tried to do:

```
git update-index --chmod=+x check_services.sh
```

on the git folder that gets checkouted by Jenkins but no luck.

Any help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you include `#!/bin/bash` as the process interpreter on the first line of your script? If you have made it executable to yourself or to the group it is owned by with (`chmod 0755 filename`) then it may be having trouble determining the correct interpreter.

Comment: Using `sh check_services.sh` requires reading permissions, instead of executing

Comment: try ssh'ng into the host and then change the permissions. Git might also not have permission to change the permissions. Changing it manually might do the work, or you can also change the script's owner to jenkins

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yes I included the process interpreter

Comment: @YaroslavSurzhikov how do I give the script reading permissions on jenkins itself automatically?

Comment: just use chmod 755 after the clone is done .

Answer (score 16):

I got it working with adding this to the GIT repo:
git update-index --chmod=+x check_services.sh

Answer (score 9):

My preference is to keep access permissions for individual files out of my git repo, favoring a method to handle this right inside the pipeline instead.  Simply run the chmod ahead of the execution of the script, to give permissions to the workspace.  Using declarative:

```
    stage('My Stage') {
        steps {
            sh "chmod +x -R ${env.WORKSPACE}"
            sh "./my-script.sh"
        }
    }
```

NOTE: For those who don't know this yet, the other requirement is to explicitly tell pipeline where the script is relative to the workspace.  Just using sh "my-script.sh" won't work.

Comment: This will change all of the files in the workspace to be executable, not exactly what you want. sh "chmod +x ./my-script.sh" would target just the one file