# jenkins with docker build pipeline fail - Permission denied

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I run jenkins with docker and when I start build pipeline I am getting this error:

```
sh: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/fake_message_main@2@tmp/durable-ac93e82e/jenkins-log.txt: Permission denied
sh: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/fake_message_main@2@tmp/durable-ac93e82e/jenkins-result.txt.tmp: Permission denied
touch: cannot touch '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/fake_message_main@2@tmp/durable-ac93e82e/jenkins-log.txt': Permission denied
mv: cannot stat '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/fake_message_main@2@tmp/durable-ac93e82e/jenkins-result.txt.tmp': No such file or directory
touch: cannot touch '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/fake_message_main@2@tmp/durable-ac93e82e/jenkins-log.txt': Permission denied
touch: cannot touch '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/fake_message_main@2@tmp/durable-ac93e82e/jenkins-log.txt': Permission denied
touch: cannot touch '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/fake_message_main@2@tmp/durable-ac93e82e/jenkins-log.txt': Permission denied
touch: cannot touch '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/fake_message_main@2@tmp/durable-ac93e82e/jenkins-log.txt': Permission denied
```

this is my Jenkinsfile:

```
    pipeline {
        agent any 
        
        stages {
            stage('Check Docker') {
                steps {
                    echo 'checking if docker exists...'
                    sh 'docker --version'
                }
            }
            stage ('Test'){
                parallel {
                    stage ('Test Rocky 8.1') {
                        agent {
                            docker {
                                image 'localhost:5000/centos7:latest'
                                args '-u jenkins:jenkins'
                            }
                        }
                        steps {
                            script {
                                echo env.WORKSPACE
                                echo 'Building Rpm...'
                                sh 'python3 --version'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            stage ('Build'){
                parallel {
                    stage ('Test Rocky 8.1') {
                        agent {
                            docker {
                                image 'localhost:5000/centos7:latest'
                                args '-u root:root'
                            }
                        }
                        steps {
                            echo 'Building Rpm...'
                            sh 'python3 --version'
                        }
                        post {
                            always {
                                cleanWs()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            stage("deploy") {
                steps {
                    echo 'Hello World'
                    echo "deploying the aplication... wooooow!!!"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

this is how I run jenkins with docker:

```
docker run -u 0 \
  --privileged --rm \
  --name jenkins -d \
  -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker \
  -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home \
  -e JAVA_OPTS="-Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true" \
  jenkins/jenkins:latest
```

Everything works fine if I replace `args -u jenkins:jenkins` with `args -u root:root` or if I enter shell of running jenkins container and quickly change ownership to jenkins give full permissions to `/var/jenkins_home/workspace/fake_message_main@2@tmp/` before build starts.
I tried [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46766121/permission-denied-error-jenkins-shell-script/61956744#61956744) solutions but nothing work and some on Jenkins forum. Any help is appreciated!

edited, this is how I built my centos7 container:

```
FROM centos:centos7
ADD files/tmp /tmp
RUN rpm --import /tmp/*.pub
RUN yum clean all
RUN yum -y install openssh-clients
RUN yum -y install \
    epel-release
RUN yum makecache && yum -y install \
    python27 \
    python-pip \
    python-requests \
    python2-mock \
    python34-devel \
    python34-mock \
    rpmdevtools  \
    rpmlint \
    rpm-build \
    python-devel \
    python2-devel \
    python2-setuptools \
    python34-setuptools \
    python36-devel \
    python36-setuptools \
    which \
    perl-devel \
    perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker
RUN yum -y install \
    gcc \
    zlib zlib-devel lzma xz-devel \
    openssl-devel ncurses-devel bzip2-devel \
    readline-devel libffi-devel sqlite-devel
RUN yum -y group install "Development Tools"

RUN groupadd -g 1000 jenkins && \
    useradd -m jenkins -u 1000 -g 1000

ADD files/etc/rpm-repo.conf /root/scripts/rpm-repo.conf
ADD files/scripts/scp-upload.sh /root/scripts/scp-upload.sh
ADD files/scripts/pyenv.sh /home/jenkins/
ADD files/etc/argo.repo /etc/yum.repos.d
RUN pip install httmock coverage=='4.5.4' unittest2 discover
RUN pip install -U "pip==20.*" "setuptools<45.0.0" && pip install pipenv
RUN pip3 install -U pip setuptools
RUN pip3 install mock httmock tox tox-pyenv requests pytest coverage unittest-xml-reporting aiofiles lxml unidecode
RUN yum install -y python3-aiohttp python3-bonsai python3-avro
COPY files/build-rpm.sh /home/jenkins/build-rpm.sh
USER jenkins
WORKDIR /home/jenkins
RUN curl https://pyenv.run | bash
RUN mv $HOME/.pyenv $HOME/pyenv
RUN source $HOME/pyenv.sh && pyenv install --list | grep ' 3.7' | tail -n1 | xargs pyenv install
RUN source $HOME/pyenv.sh && pyenv install --list | grep ' 3.8' | tail -n1 | xargs pyenv install
RUN source $HOME/pyenv.sh && pyenv install --list | grep ' 3.9' | tail -n1 | xargs pyenv install
RUN source $HOME/pyenv.sh && pyenv install --list | grep 'mambaforge' | tail -n1 | xargs pyenv install
RUN source $HOME/pyenv.sh && pyenv local $(pyenv versions | grep 'mambaforge' | head -n1)
RUN source $HOME/pyenv.sh && mamba create -y -n ams-py310 python=3.10
RUN source $HOME/pyenv.sh && pyenv local system
RUN rm $HOME/.python-version
USER root
WORKDIR /root
RUN su - jenkins rpmdev-setuptree
```

Comment: Is there a `jenkins` user and group in the docker image?

Comment: This is very likely a permissions issue in `/var/jenkins_home/workspace/fake_message_main@2@tmp/durable-ac93e82e/` You should either add Jenkins to the root group, or allow for more permissions on the directory and the files created in it. You could either `chmod` it or set a more permissive `umask`.

Comment: @MatthewSchuchard I edited my post, I put dockerfile that I use to build centos7 image

Comment: @Uberhumus it works if I open jenkins shell with `/bin/bash` and there I give those two commands: `chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/jenkins_home/workspace/fake-message_main@2@tmp/
chmod -R 777 /var/jenkins_home/workspace/fake-message_main@2@tmp/` when I run build. That is how I know it works, but how to put those commands in Jenkinsfile so that it gives permissions to user jenkins:jenkins when build starts? Or is there something awfully wrong with `jenkinsfile` synthax or `dockerfile`?

Comment: @dean89, the 1st or 2nd command suffices. You don't need both `chmod` and `chown`. If you have the permissions for it, it might also work in a Jenkinsfile in a `sh` command. But honestly running `chmod 777 /var/jenkins_home` or better yet adding Jenkins (or the UID 1000) to the root group would also work. Or better better yet, creating a new group that includes jenkins, root and UID 1000, and chowning `/var/jenkins_home` to root:new_group. Test before running in prod! I'm AFK, and can't test to be sure here.

Comment: LMK of it works.

Comment: @Uberhumus it didn't work. I did everything you wrote, first I tried `sh 'chmod 777 /var/jenkins_home'` (something which I already did before) in `Jenkinsfile`, when it didn't work, I only added `chmod 777 /var/jenkins_home` and finally since first two suggestions didn't work I created new group `addgroup new_group`, `adduser jenkins new_group`,`adduser root new_group` and `chown -R root:new_group /var/jenkins_home` (I didn't need sudo because I was already in root)

Comment: When you ran `chmod 777`, you didn't add `-R` right? I should have mentioned that...

Comment: @Uberhumus I tried both ways, with and without -R, it doesn't work, same issue

Answer (score 2):

The root cause is you mount the host directory `jenkins_home` to container by option `-v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home`.

When user `jenkins` access `/var/jenkins_home` inside container, actually it's to access `jenkins_home` on host.

The owner of host directory `jenkins_home` is not the user `jenkins` which you created for container by Dockerfile.  Thus the access is denied.

**Important:** Even you have user or group with same name on host and container, but OS won't teat both are same if the id of both are not same.

Three approaches can address your issue:

1. Mount host user and group to container

- Run container by option `-v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd` and `-v /etc/group:/etc/group`, it leads the owner of host directory `jenkins_home` can be found in container,
- Run container with the owner of host directory `jenkins_home`, you can use user id or name here. `-u <user name or id of host directory "jenkins_home">`

2. Change host directory `jenkins_home` owner to 1000:1000 (user and group id of user `jenkins` created by Dockerfile for container), then you can run container with option `-u 1000:1000`, but `-u jenkins:jenkins` (OS match user and group by Id among host and container, not by name)
3. Use the user and group id of the owner of host directory `jenkins_home` to create user `jenkins` in Dockerfile, then run container with owner of host directory `jenkins_home`.

```
ARG JENKINS_HOME_USER_ID
ARG JENKINS_HOME_GROUP_ID

RUN groupadd -g $JENKINS_HOME_GROUP_ID jenkins && \
    useradd -m jenkins -u $JENKINS_HOME_USER_ID -g $JENKINS_HOME_GROUP_ID
```

A core point of the 3 approaches is to make the owner of host directory `jenkins_home` becomes an existing and valid user inside container.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved this issue:

- first I ran jenkins container as root:

  `docker run -u 0 --privileged --rm --name jenkins -d -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -e JAVA_OPTS="-Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true" jenkins/jenkins:latest`
- and I went inside container with: `docker exec -it jenkins /bin/bash`, and changed `docker.sock` permissions `chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock`.
- Then I used `docker commit` to save those changes and again ran container but this time with `-u jenkins:jenkins` instead of `-u 0`.

  `docker run -u jenkins:jenkins --privileged --rm --name jenkins -d -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker -v jenkins-home:/var/jenkins_home -e JAVA_OPTS="-Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true" jenkins/jenkins:latest`

I also installed Docker plugins in Jenkins and it worked.

I don't know if that helped but I have changed `jenkins_home` to `jenkins-home` by reading [this](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/issues/493) GitHub issue.

Thanks to everyone who helped me!