# permission denied in jenkins pipeline running bash script

Tags: bash, jenkins-pipeline, containers, sh

Team, permission denied when trying to run script via jenkins pipeline any clue what could be the reason that shell script is not getting executed? I tried all combos I could.. still looking.. I gave all 777 perms in pipeline itself. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43372035/permission-denied-when-executing-the-jenkins-sh-pipeline-step) but no luck.

> /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/team/code-coverage-WIP@tmp/durable-29cd82d6/script.sh:
> 4: //: Permission denied

```
  steps {
    preBuild(bazel_init)
    container('main') {
      sh '''
        pwd
        ls -ltr
        ls -ltr scripts/test-report.sh
        chmod 777 scripts/test-report.sh
        ls -ltr scripts/test-report.sh
        BAZEL_OPTS="--config=ci --config=remote_cache_ci"
        scripts/test-report.sh
      '''.stripIndent()
```

output

```
+ ls -ltr scripts/test-report.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jenkins jenkins 238 Dec 9 06:18 scripts/test-report.sh

+ chmod 777 scripts/test-report.sh
+ ls -ltr scripts/test-report.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jenkins jenkins 238 Dec 9 06:18 scripts/test-report.sh

+ BAZEL_OPTS=--config=ci --config=remote_cache_ci
+ scripts/test-report.sh

/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/team/code-coverage-WIP@tmp/durable-29cd82d6/script.sh: 4: //: Permission denied
```

**the script is**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
which bazel
bazelbin=$(bazel info bazel-bin)
target="//src/cmd/gocoverage"
cmd="${bazelbin}/src/cmd/gocoverage/gocoverage_/gocoverage"
bazel build $target
$cmd -goprefix=go.corp.nvidia.com/maglev ${GOCOVERAGE_OPTS} $@
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove `#!/bin/bash` from the script and then use like below in pipeline

```
                              sh '''
                                chmod 777 -R scripts
                                BAZEL_OPTS="--config=ci --config=remote_cache_ci"
                                bash scripts/test-report.sh
                              '''.stripIndent()
```