# Jenkins permission error when using Docker agent for python

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, fastapi

I have an Jenkins Server running in an Ubuntu VM and it has access to docker an the host system via the Docker Jenkins plugin/Docker. I have a pipeline for a FastAPI app but I am getting an error when installing packages :

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.local'Check the permissions.
```

This is how my Jenkinsfile looks like :

```
pipeline {
agent {
    docker {
          image 'python:3.9-slim'
    }
      }
triggers {
    githubPush()
}
stages {
    
    stage('Setup'){
       steps{   
          sh 'python -m venv .venv'
          sh '. .venv/bin/activate'
          sh 'pip install -r requirements.txt'  
        }
     }
       stage('Unit Tests'){ 

       steps{
           sh 'pytest'
        }
     }        

  }
```

}

I have tried suggestions in other threads but none worked for me so far :

1. Adding --user flag

   pip install --user -r requirements.txt
2. Adding the jenkins user to docker group

   usermod  -aG  docker jenkins
3. Adding the jenkins user to sudo group

   usermod -aG sudo jenkins

In all cases I am getting the same error , with log as attached below :

```
Started by user gold
Obtained Jenkinsfile from xxxxxxx
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Python-Project
...
...
+ docker inspect -f . python:3.9-slim
.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
Jenkins does not seem to be running inside a container
$ docker run -t -d -u 113:120 -w /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Python-Project -v 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Python-Project:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Python-Project:rw,z -v ... python:3.9-slim cat
$ docker top xxx -eo pid,comm
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Setup)
[Pipeline] sh
+ python -m venv .venv
[Pipeline] sh
+ . .venv/bin/activate
+ deactivate nondestructive
+ [ -n  ]
+ [ -n  ]
+ [ -n  -o -n  ]
+ [ -n  ]
+ unset VIRTUAL_ENV
+ [ ! nondestructive = nondestructive ]
+ VIRTUAL_ENV=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Python-Project/.venv
+ export VIRTUAL_ENV
+ _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
...
+ _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1=$ 
+ PS1=(.venv) $ 
+ export PS1
+ [ -n  -o -n  ]
[Pipeline] sh
+ pip install -r requirements.txt
WARNING: The directory '/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you should use sudo's -H flag.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
....
....
Collecting six==1.16.0
  Downloading six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Successfully built python-multipart
Installing collected packages: rfc3986, charset-normalizer, xxx, ... fastapi
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.local'
Check the permissions.

WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 23.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
[Pipeline] }
.....
$ docker stop --time=1 xxx
$ docker rm -f --volumes xxx
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
....
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

However when I override the Docker Agent's user the pipeline runs successfully but to me this **seems like an ugly solution at best** :

```
  agent {
    docker {
         image 'python:3.8'
         args '-u root --privileged'
    }
      }
```

What exactly causes this error?

Is there a more elegant way of handling this ?

Comment: From your logs and the steps, it's observable that each invocation of `sh` in `steps` starts a new shell which means that the activation of `venv` is only limited to that step before `pip install`. So, you need to combine these three steps into a single invocation of `sh` e.g. `sh ''' \n command-1 \n command-2 \n command-N'''` (`\n` = newline)

Comment: Can check below link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43372035/permission-denied-when-executing-the-jenkins-sh-pipeline-step